# MySQL - Force DROP TABLE in EVENT without confirm

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In MySQL phpmyadmin environment, when i create an event in which a DROP TABLE statement is set to occur, DROP TABLE (silently) does not occur, because my MySQL install, apparently, expects a confirmation.

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS test.target_ultra_sync ;
CREATE EVENT test.target_ultra_sync 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 SECOND
DO 
DROP  TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`ultra`;
CREATE  TABLE `test`.`ultra` AS SELECT * FROM `target_ultra`;
```

The same occurs with TRUNCATE and DELETE.

How can i suppress this behavior?

Comment: never heard off MySQL needing a confirmation when dropping a table..

Comment: now you have.  :)  PS: try dropping a table in mysql phpmyadmin (might be my install, as i said)

Comment: that confirmation is from PHPMyAdmin not from MySQL..

Comment: the confirmation popup occurs in phpmyadmin, but mysql is the one who controls events and stored procedures, or am i mistaken?  I have no problem with phpmyadmin, i run the sql and create the evenmt.  Yet, when the event occurs for the second time, beyond the scope of phpmyadmin, the drop table command is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get any prompts in phpMyAdmin from the event scheduler when I try a variant of your event.

It appears that your event syntax is off just a bit (I had to apply a minor modification), as you have compound statements after the `DO` that needs a `BEGIN` and `END` section like so:

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS test.target_ultra_sync ;

CREATE EVENT test.target_ultra_sync 
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 SECOND
      DO
         BEGIN 
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`ultra`;
            CREATE TABLE `test`.`ultra` AS SELECT * FROM `target_ultra`;
         END
```

After that event change is applied, you can then check that the `Executed_events` variable is counting (roughly twice a minute based on your `30 second` setting) by running this SQL command:

```
show status WHERE variable_name = 'Executed_events'
```

After you've run that query once in phpMyAdmin, you can simply refresh the query to get updated results as shown in the image below.

[image]

Of course, if you have other scheduled events it will be hard to know if the counts are strictly from this event alone, unless the others have a longer time that do not run as frequently.

Should you find that the `Executed_events` count is **NOT** increasing after creating the event, ensure that the event scheduler is running! This can be checked in phpMyAdmin here:

[image]

Comment: it is a silent problem.  I don't know if i solved the issue, or if produced a workaround.  I managed to avoid the problem calling procedures, which in turn did whatever the event was restricted from doing.  Nevertheless, in the end, I decided to simply run a php script as a recurring Cron job.  I lose some overhead, but have infinitely more control and latitude.

THANK YOU, YOUR ANSWER WAS UPVOTED.  :)